# Typescript merge n arrays of objects

Tags: typescript

I have a `type` named `IndexedObject`, which is defined as:

```js
type IndexedObject<T extends {} = { [k: string]: any }> = T & { _i: number }

// It just appends an index "_i" to the object
// The "_i" index is assigned in the first function of the chain,
// and then it doesn't get changed anywhere else
```

The reason I use this is that I have an input array, and several functions that transform and filter it, and I need to keep track of the original index of each element (it's probably  not important in the main question, but I explained it just in case)

So I have an arbitrary number of arrays of type `IndexedObject<T1>[]`, `IndexedObject<T2>[]`, etc., with `T1`, `T2`, etc. being different object types with arbitrary keys. And I want to merge them into one array of merged objects. for example:

```js
interface T1 {
    id: number
    name: string
}

interface T2 {
    status: boolean
    message: string
}

let arr1: IndexedObject<T1>[] = [
    {_i: 0, id: 201, name: 'a'}, 
    {_i: 3, id: 5, name: 'h'}
]

let arr2: IndexedObject<T2>[] = [
    {_i: 0, status: true, message: '1234'},
    {_i: 1, status: false, message: '5678'},
    {_i: 4, status: false, message: '9065'}
]

// merged:
let merged = [
    {_i: 0, id: 201, name: 'a', status: true, message: '1234'},
    {_i: 1, status: false, message: '5678'},
    {_i: 3, id: 5, name: 'h'},
    {_i: 4, status: false, message: '9065'}
]
```

The merging itself is not an issue. This is the function I wrote:

```js
function mergeIndexedArrays(...arrays: IndexedObject[][]) {
    return arrays.reduce((result, array) => {
        for (let a of array) {
            result[a._i] = { ...result[a._i], ...a }
        }
        return result
    }, [])
}
```

The problem is with typing. I need the return type of the merge function to dynamically contain the keys of all the input types (here `T1` and `T2`). How can I do this?

Note that there are an arbitrary number of arrays.

I tried to achieve this using `variadic tuple types` but I couldn't figure it out.

Thank you

Comment: Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOAQMm)?

Comment: @caTS Yes! That's exactly what I need. Can you write up an answer and explain your solution? Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, we want to "extract" all the types in the indexed objects (`infer`), then intersect them together (and also make the result a Partial, since they aren't guaranteed to exist).

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never;

type InferTypes<A> = A extends IndexedObject<infer U>[][] ? U : never;

function mergeIndexedArrays<Arrays extends IndexedObject[][]>(...arrays: Arrays): Partial<UnionToIntersection<InferTypes<Arrays>>>[];
function mergeIndexedArrays(...arrays: IndexedObject[][]) {
    return arrays.reduce((result, array) => {
        for (let a of array) {
            result[a._i] = { ...result[a._i], ...a }
        }
        return result
    }, [])
}
```

Then we can use rest parameters to collect all the arrays into the generic type `Arrays`. Also, I have moved the signature into an overload so it doesn't cause annoying type errors in the function body.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDwgg8gIwFYQMbAA8AKlCsBIgM5QDeAvlALx1QDaA1gFxRXABOASzgBzALo8AhnBBR6APmZRSAMlYB9QTzgBXALaYI-OQFgAUOeEV+AM0l5oxAIx1zUd1EEJt+w-zcecJJ6EDx8QqLm9OaWcNZ2DsoATK5mHrzAksA6VDyYAPb5ADYQ0gHuIVRUkiKhGREiUTFmJcBQkvz8TjzwSKgYOPhEzvJsYkps5XSaPAAMADSe3lBJs06LQSE8AOSS2-SLU7QzUADMi148AKwbwXXbABb75mLNre2dST2IKGhYuAQSElRuMWJM0h5jlooAsMlkcjwBDoIItKtVajsnElTgAWfbzI4ndZw7K5KB2IpUFFQNE1e5XABsAHYABz4wnQnGLPjwskUqmoiBVOk7ACcswZV2eZleFjMoEgUAAqnBBPk4MR8vBrFSCGq4IQlYoWAEABRKsjICjUdoyKAAfigpu4yoAlEx5AA3fJeKDaCCeoyuy3WhA0U3OnjCGxGWDur0+hDBx0wP1QOABowAbmaCug8Bj-GI4CFhAAgsaoGWQ5Qw7Afv1-kNCNHY0axmMHcq0xnA-wc3KbDo4Hr1TSjLVer8EGXOpIQFRy3OFzWbVPG4MCB2xPJTQA6A8dfjzsmz48L108AAKHWAgkkRUNqvVmu1Rl1d-VhALRmLkEXZ4nvIwFjAOQ4jp+cDjvwk4NmggELvuh7LmS65-JuwDbsGtBTPwEDZPwUFHiee54QgOgOBGeFUDoRTAIsxEgMGHqpOk6Q2Pkximu8khQPkNgfOe2FTGxHjUbRmGSHumigqwB6kUKElsFJMmLPJvHRBComaaJ7h4QRUHiXRUwHOwYiuk0cp4OqfDQbUCBKCEMEQGhM4oaaR7EkeSSugO5jWXAVDFBAe5FPkIimk59m+UAA)